# NSPredicate to not include Loop and Bounce Live Photos

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, photosframework, phfetchoptions

In my app I only show assets the user can edit, so I only show photos - no videos. New in iOS 11 Live Photos have two effects that effectively turn the photo into a video - Loop and Bounce. These Live Photos cannot be edited in the Photos app - the plugins button is disabled. I need to filter those out in my `PHFetchResult`. But `mediaType` of `image` still includes these 'live videos'. How can I exclude those from the fetch? Maybe something to do with the `playbackStyle` of `PHAsset`?

```
let photoLibraryFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil)  
let assetCollection = photoLibraryFetchResult.firstObject!  

let imagesOnlyFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()  
imagesOnlyFetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)  

let assetsFetchResults = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: imagesOnlyFetchOptions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the `playbackStyle` value. ([Read more here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phasset?changes=latest_beta))

The enum has the following options:

```
case image
case imageAnimated
case livePhoto
case unsupported
case video
case videoLooping
```

Comment: Cool, the syntax for this is: `NSPredicate(format: "playbackStyle = %d or playbackStyle = %d", PHAsset.PlaybackStyle.image.rawValue, PHAsset.PlaybackStyle.livePhoto.rawValue)`